# Make a video with few words in android

Tags: java, android, video

i need make a video in android with few Pictures (a black image with a text) and i need that every image have a 2 seconds duration.

I tried with jcodec, but i cant make it.
How is the best way to make it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can always make an application that does that in Eclipse of Android Studios. For the basic algorithm, upon the user clicking a button "start", you can move on to the next activity. After this activity starts, you can cycle through a series of images with text, and use some type of time loop, so that the array will go from one item to the next in 2 seconds.

Comment: yes, i have the app, but dont work.
I used jcodec, but i cant add few images per second